# Invalid block tag: 'bootstrap_icon', expected 'endblock'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to use [django-bootstrap3](http://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) package with my project.

I have built my template like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">{% bootstrap_icon "star" %} All customers</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        All your customers are listed here in alphabetical order. In this panel you can update and delete
        your customer informations.
    </div>
</div>
    {{ customers }}

{% endblock %}
```

But i'm getting

> Invalid block tag: 'bootstrap_icon', expected 'endblock'

Error.

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}
```

Are in base.html file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should load  `{% load bootstrap3 %}` inside your template.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}


{% block content %}

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">{% bootstrap_icon "star" %} All customers</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        All your customers are listed here in alphabetical order. In this panel you can update and delete
        your customer informations.
    </div>
</div>
    {{ customers }}

{% endblock %}
```